# What's the intuition behind the "undertermined-ness" of mean and Variance of student distribution for $n=1$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

The student's distribution is such that its mean and variance are said to be "undertermined" when there is a single degree of freedom. When there are two, the variance is infinite...

What's the intuition behind these results ?

Comment: With $X \sim t_1$ you get a Cauchy distribution with $E[|X|]=\infty$ and $E[X^2]=\infty$.  Since you have a distribution symmetric about $0$, this results in no defined mean $E[X]$, and since variance is $E[(X-E[X])^2]$ not having a defined mean means result in not having a defined variance either.